# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value" Exception when accessing FireStore sub-collections

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have the below Firestore collections.

[image]

"User" is added as an reference to the "uploads" document.

This is the code that I use and it works fine when I dont have that "reference" object.

```
return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('uploads')
      .where('type', isEqualTo: type)
      .snapshots,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      process(snapshot.data.documents);
  });
```

But when I add this user reference, I get the below exception with Flutter.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11714): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@147888c5
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:249)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeMethodCall(StandardMethodCodec.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:190)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevc.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevd.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
E/AndroidRuntime(11714):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

When I convert the "reference" type to other types, it works.

**Question:**

How do I modify my code to fetch both uploads and its users reference details?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have raised this issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12989), and it's still appeared as open on their github. At this stage, I don't think you can use `reference` type. Maybe try to use `ID` for now.

Comment: Guess that's the only solution. It's a blocker for me. Using an ID required additional call to be made which I don't want.

Comment: Can you share some suggestion on how you use ID for better performance?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/343 Looks like its awaiting to be approved and merged.

Comment: @Purus oh I didn't notice that, good news :) Hope we can use it soon. Anyway, we use redux for our app, and store collection as app state, then filter by Id locally.

Comment: Not sure when it will be available for release :(

Comment: Any document for beginners to start with Redux?